# How to set public Google Calendar embed URL to use client's local time zone?

Tags: google-calendar, url, time-zone

I've embedded a public google calendar

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=WEEK&src=alecjacobson%40gmail.com
```

This shows the calendar using New York's timezone (my calendar's default), regardless if the person viewing it is, e.g., in Chicago.

I can add

```
&ctz=America%2FChicago
```

And this will force it to be Chicago's timezone. But I'd like it to use the client's local timezone *where ever* they are. I'm hoping for something like:

```
&ctz=local
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In case it helps anyone else who wanders this way, using `&ctz=America%2FNew_York` (note the underscore) gets you Eastern time.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Google Calendar doesn't have a URL parameter to display an embeded calendar in the user's local timezone.

Instead

- you need to use JavaScript or something like that. The following posts could give some hints:

  - [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091372/1595451)
  - [Support User Time Zone in Embedded Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31821974/1595451)
- tell the user to add your calendar to his/her calendar

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the "viewer" timezone.
[image: settings]

Comment: How do you get to these calendar settings?

Comment: I agree that it is not at all clear that this is actually answering OP's question as I cannot find this menu either.